# Find the sum of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I have a series $$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k \; \bmod \; 3) * P(P(t)\; =\; k) $$ , where $P(t)$ is the Poisson process with lambda intensity (calculate the mathematical expectation of the process ($Р(t)$ mod 3)) , т.е. $$P(P(t) = k) = \frac{(\lambda  t)^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda t}$$
I calculate it like this
$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (0) * P(P(t)\; =\; 3k) + \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (1) * P(P(t)\; =\; 3k+1) + \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (2) * P(P(t)\; =\; 3k+2)$$
Please tell me how to calculate
$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (1) * \frac{(\lambda  t)^{3k+1}}{3k+1!}e^{-\lambda t} = e^{-\lambda t}\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (1) * \frac{(\lambda  t)^{3k+1}}{3k+1!}$$
I can’t figure out how to calculate, maybe through Maclaurin, but it’s not suitable for the decomposition of the degree e.

Comment: Hint: consider the Maclaurin series for $e^{\lambda t} + \zeta^2 e^{\zeta\lambda t} + \zeta e^{\zeta^2\lambda t}$ where $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/3}$.

Comment: Look up multisection of series to extract the parts from the series for $e^x$.

Comment: @GregMartin Could you please give a little more details? I have tried to decompose
$$\zeta ^ 2   e^{\zeta \lambda t}  =  \zeta ^ 2 \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\zeta \lambda  t)^{k}}{k!} = \zeta ^ 2 \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(cos(\frac23\pi)+ i\; sin(\frac23\pi))(\lambda  t)^{k}}{k!} =  \zeta ^ 2 \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\frac{-1} 2+ i\; \frac {\sqrt{3}} 2)^k(\lambda  t)^{k}}{k!} $$
But how can I get closer to my original series?

Comment: Instead of using sines and cosines, use the fact that $\zeta^3=1$ to write every expression of the form $\zeta^k$ as one of $1,\zeta,\zeta^2$